# Postgresql 9.2 syntax issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, syntax-error

I am trying to execute this query using Postgresql 9.2

```
WITH udetail as (select(regexp_split_to_array('user@domain', E'\\@+')))
select * from udetail[1];
```

Buy it gives me a syntax error near where the start of `'['`. This same query is working fine under version 9.3. So I'm wonder if there's an alternative way of writing the query to get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
WITH udetail(x) as (
   select(regexp_split_to_array('user@domain', E'\\@+')))
select x[1] from udetail;
```

I don't think you can index a table expression like `udetail` in your case. It is the *column* of the table expression that is of array type. Hence, you can use an array subscript number on the column, not on the table itself.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb/955)

Comment: That's for the more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an alias either as the query parameter:

```
with udetail(arr) as (
    select regexp_split_to_array('user@domain', E'\\@+')
    )
select arr[1] from udetail;
```

or as column alias:

```
with udetail as (
    select regexp_split_to_array('user@domain', E'\\@+') as arr
    )
select arr[1] from udetail;
```

You can also do it without aliases:

```
with udetail as (
    select regexp_split_to_array('user@domain', E'\\@+')
    )
select regexp_split_to_array[1] from udetail;
```